# powershell で mkvirtualenv TestEnv を実行するとエラーになる

Tags: python, powershell

poewrshellを使って、Data Visualizationを学びはじめた者です。
Pythonのversionは2.7
windowsは8.1を使用しています。

私の、システム環境変数パスは、下記の通りです。

```
c:\python27\;c:\python27\scripts;c:\python27\tools\scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio 2010\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

Virtualenvwrapperをインストールし、`mkvirtualenv TestEnv` を実行したのですが、以下のエラーが得られます。

```
PS C:\windows\system32> mkvirtualenv TestEnv
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\windows\system32\python.exe"  "c:\python27\scripts\virtualenv.exe" TestEnv
```

どなたか、何かアイデアのございます方、お力を貸して頂けますと助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"C:\windows\system32\python.exe"` は存在していますか？
あるのなら、アクセス権の問題、ないのならPythonインストールの問題でしょう。

Pythonを一度完全に削除してから、再インストールすることをお勧めします。

なお、他に出されている質問全て、同じ問題で発生しているように見えます。
Pythonをどうやってインストールしたのか分からないので、その手順や利用したインストーラなどの情報があれば問題点が明確になるかもしれません。

Comment: 清水川様。
C:\Windows\System32　の中に、
”python.exe”存在しました。
また、同じディレクトリ中に、pythonw.exeというものも存在しました。

どのようにpythonをインストールしたか定かではありません。。申し訳ないです。
pythonを綺麗に削除して、綺麗にインストールする何かオススメの方法などございましたら教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: また、アクセス権はどのように許可すればよいのでしょうか！？

Comment: どのようにしてインストールしたのか分からないのであれば、アドバイスのしようがありません。Windowsの「プログラムのアンインストールと変更」などからアンインストールしてみてください。
あるいは別のところに再インストールするとう方法もあるでしょう。